# Error in importing MatTabChangeEvent

Tags: angular-material, angular5, angular-cdk

I am trying to use the angular material library.
I have added the dependency for @angular/material in package.json as follows

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
```

When I use

```
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material';
```

It throws the error while compilation

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts:28:5
TS2416: Property '_stepHeader' in type 'MatStepper' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CdkStepper'.
Type 'QueryList<ElementRef>' is not assignable to type 'QueryList<FocusableOption>'.
Type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to type 'FocusableOption'.
  Property 'focus' is missing in type 'ElementRef'.
```

I haven't added any code related to angular material, except that import line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have the same versions of Angular CDK and Material, as well as have the Angular version for Angular Material and CDK.

In this case, upgrade all your dependencies to Angular 6:

```
npm install @angular/cdk @angular/material
```

Or:

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 3):

in angular 9 the folder structure has changed

```
"@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
```

to get the type use

```
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs';
```